# Why do robust linear models give smaller standard errors?

Tags: r, least-squares, robust, robust-standard-error

I've always read and been told that for heteroskedastic errors a normal OLS fit will generate standard errors that are too small, leading to a false degree of confidence in coefficient estimates. Robust techniques should lead to higher SE estimates and more realistic p-values etc.

I've recently tried to check this and found that almost invariably I get smaller SEs with robust techniques. Here's an example using lm() and then three robust approaches: rlm() from MASS, lmrob() from robustbase and vcovHC from sandwich

```
library(MASS)
library(robustbase)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

set.seed(98765)

# Generate X values
X1 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 20)

# Generate Y values
Y1 <- 100 + X1^3 + rnorm(80, 0, 2*X1^2)

X1 <- factor(X1)

# Look at how heteroskedastic it all is
plot(Y1~ X1)

# estimates for OLS fit
summary(lm(Y1 ~ X1))

# estimates for robust fit from rlm
summary(rlm(Y1~X1, method = "MM"))

# estimates for robust fit from lmrob
summary(lmrob(Y1~X1, method = "MM"))

# estimates using vcovHC
ols_mod <- lm(Y1 ~ X1)
coeftest(ols_mod, vcov = vcovHC(ols_mod))
```

These are the coefficient tables I get from each approach

```
lm coefficients
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  100.559      4.747  21.184  < 2e-16 ***
X12            5.578      6.713   0.831 0.408636    
X13           25.209      6.713   3.755 0.000337 ***
X14           72.021      6.713  10.728  < 2e-16 ***

  rlm coefficients NB using M-estimation gives qualitatively simlar results
             Value    Std. Error t value 
(Intercept) 100.5590   2.5228    39.8597
X12           5.5767   3.5678     1.5631
X13          20.5391   3.5678     5.7568
X14          51.9630   3.5678    14.5644

lmrob coefficients
               Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    100.559      0.421 238.844  < 2e-16 ***
  X12            5.577      1.562   3.570 0.000622 ***
  X13           20.541      5.649   3.636 0.000501 ***
  X14           51.971     11.236   4.625 1.51e-05 ***

vcovHC estimates
                Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   100.55931    0.44463 226.1658 < 2.2e-16 ***
  X12           5.57798    1.57943   3.5317 0.0007057 ***
  X13          25.20907    4.20694   5.9923 6.459e-08 ***
  X14          72.02087    8.66493   8.3118 2.783e-12 ***
```

So rlm() gives lower SEs across the board, and lmrob() and vcovHC() give SEs that are lower except for the factor level with the very highest variance. Looking around I can find some discussion on when robust methods should give lower standard errors ([e.g. here](http://chrisauld.com/2012/10/31/the-intuition-of-robust-standard-errors/)) but these seem to be saying that this will only happen under very specific circumstances, which do not apply here.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me and give me some insight as to why these robust methods are giving SEs that are usually *smaller* than those form OLS rather than *larger*? I'm not a proper statistician and the inner workings of these methods are a bit beyond me so I might be missing something obvious...

Thanks for any help

Comment: I believe this would be easier to understand if you didn't turn X1 into a factor variable. Basically, the smaller residuals for lower values means that we can estimate the intercept with lower uncertainty and the higher residuals for larger values means that we can estimate the slope only with higher uncertainty than if residuals were homoskedastic. After discretization this results in smaller standard errors for groups with small estimates and larger standard errors for groups with large estimates.